# Mailcow: mail for gmail.com loops back to myself

Tags: debian, routing, kvm, postfix, proxmox

I have a dedicated server with Proxmox (previously with VMWare).
There is a VM with Mailcow-dockerized installed.
The interface on hypervisor **vmbr0** is NATed (NAT on physical NIC with subnet 192.168.200.0/24).
The Mailcow VM has LAN IP 192.168.200.4/24 and traffic from Internet is being forwarded using Firewalld rules with masquerade enabled

OS on hypervisor: Debian 11 bullseye, network configured manually:

```
iface enp9s0 inet static
  address 65.21.XXX.XXX
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  gateway 65.21.XXX.XXX
  # route 65.21.XXX.XXX/26 via 65.21.XXX.XXX
  up route add -net 65.21.XXX.XXX netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 65.21.XXX.XXX dev enp9s0

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.200.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.200.0/24' -o enp9s0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.200.0/24' -o enp9s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Rules in Firewall-cmd:

```
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 8006/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
        port=25:proto=tcp:toport=25:toaddr=192.168.200.4
        port=143:proto=tcp:toport=143:toaddr=192.168.200.4
        port=465:proto=tcp:toport=465:toaddr=192.168.200.4
        port=587:proto=tcp:toport=587:toaddr=192.168.200.4
        port=993:proto=tcp:toport=993:toaddr=192.168.200.4
        port=443:proto=tcp:toport=443:toaddr=192.168.200.4
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

The problem is that mailcow (and any other mailserver) cannot send e-mails, but receives them correctly. I connected to all ports using telnet, and all are responding correctly.
The route in mailserver (I suspect there is a problem with routing, but I am not sure):

```
root@mta01:~# ip r l
default via 192.168.200.1 dev ens18 onlink
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.22.1.0/24 dev br-mailcow proto kernel scope link src 172.22.1.1
192.168.200.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.4
root@mta01:~#
```

I think that there is a problem with routing. But I also suspect, that the problem is that I NATed the interface.. But not sure.
Domains are enabled and set up correctly in DNS (double-checked A, MX, TXT, SPF, DMARC and DKIM) and Mailcow admin panel.

Also checked by telneting to from the mailserver to Google SMTP on port 25 (IP: 64.233.184.26): successful

```
root@mta01:~# telnet mta01.X.dev 25                                                                            
Trying 65.21.139.244...                                                                                                 
Connected to mta01.X.dev.                                                                                      
Escape character is '^]'.                                                                                               
220 mta01.X.dev ESMTP Postcow                                                                                  
HELO mta01.X.dev                                                                                               
250 mta01.X.dev                                                                                                
MAIL FROM: <bruno@X.dev>                                                                                       
250 2.1.0 Ok                                                                                                            
RCPT TO: <bruno.X@gmail.com>                                                                                   
554 5.7.1 <bruno.X@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

Another check - checked DNS (for outage, MTA02 has higher priority, problem is with MTA01):

```
root@mta01:~# dig +short MX X.dev
10 mta01.X.dev.
1 mta02.X.dev.

root@mta01:~# dig +short A mta01.X.dev
65.21.XXX.XXX

root@mta01:~# dig +short mx gmail.com
10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

So seems like that resolver is working fine

Errors from log:

```
32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:16 859ac05b9a6a postfix/smtp[2703]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c08::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:16 859ac05b9a6a postfix/postscreen[2704]: CONNECT from [192.168.200.1]:60460 to [172.22.1.253]:25
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:16 859ac05b9a6a whitelist_forwardinghosts: Look up 192.168.200.1 on whitelist, result 200 DUNNO
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/postscreen[2704]: PASS OLD [192.168.200.1]:60460
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/smtpd[2724]: connect from unknown[192.168.200.1]
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/smtp[2703]: warning: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.165.26]:25 greeted me with my own hostname mta01.stelmaszyk.dev
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/smtp[2703]: warning: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.165.26]:25 replied to HELO/EHLO with my own hostname mta01.stelmaszyk.dev
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/smtp[2703]: 7EA791C0F9E: to=<bruno.stelmaszyk@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.165.26]:25, delay=6.6, delays=2.9/0.01/3.7/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for gmail.com loops back to myself)
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/smtpd[2724]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.200.1] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/cleanup[2727]: 5FD1C1C10EB: message-id=<20210919074519.5FD1C1C10EB@mta01.stelmaszyk.dev>
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/bounce[2726]: 7EA791C0F9E: sender non-delivery notification: 5FD1C1C10EB
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/qmgr[353]: 5FD1C1C10EB: from=<>, size=3406, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/qmgr[353]: 7EA791C0F9E: removed
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/lmtp[2728]: 5FD1C1C10EB: to=<bruno@stelmaszyk.dev>, relay=dovecot[fd4d:6169:6c63:6f77::12]:24, delay=0.04, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <bruno@stelmaszyk.dev> YEEeGI/qRmFqGgAAggiFYw Saved)
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:45:19 859ac05b9a6a postfix/qmgr[353]: 5FD1C1C10EB: removed
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:48:39 859ac05b9a6a postfix/anvil[2725]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtpd:192.168.200.1) at Sep 19 09:45:19
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:48:39 859ac05b9a6a postfix/anvil[2725]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtpd:192.168.200.1) at Sep 19 09:45:19
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:48:39 859ac05b9a6a postfix/anvil[2725]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Sep 19 09:45:19
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:50:47 859ac05b9a6a postfix/smtps/smtpd[2741]: connect from unknown[192.168.200.1]
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:51:17 859ac05b9a6a postfix/smtps/smtpd[2741]: SSL_accept error from unknown[192.168.200.1]: lost connection
ESC[32mpostfix-mailcow_1    |ESC[0m Sep 19 09:51:17 859ac05b9a6a postfix/smtps/smtpd[2741]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[192.168.200.1
```

Does anyone see any issue in the config?

Comment: The successful `telnet` proves there's no network routing issue. Does DNS resolve on the MTA server? What error/debug messages do you get when your MTA tries to send a message?

Comment: Yes, DNS resolves.

Comment: There should be some debug/verbose logging from the MTA. Not the "sorry" message it returns to the sender but actual logging somewhere. Many MTAs log to files such as `/var/log/mail*` You can often trigger it with (eg) `echo boo | mail -v -s test {whoever}@gmail.com` (replace `{whoever}`)

Comment: dig resolved gmail mx records correctly

Comment: What was the banner line from your telnet command (I e. The next line after what you included in the question)?

Comment: 220 mta01.X.dev ESMTP Postcow

Comment: Um. `root@mta01:~# telnet mta01.X.dev 25` as now in your question is attempting to loop back; it's certainly not attempting to connect to Google. Please would you try `telnet  64.233.184.26 25` for me, and include the first banner response

Comment: ```root@mta01:~# telnet  64.233.184.26 25                                                                                  
Trying 64.233.184.26...                                                                                                 
Connected to 64.233.184.26.                                                                                             
Escape character is '^]'.                                                                                               
220-mta01.X.dev ESMTP Postcow```